# node server hosted on heroku not serving socket.io file

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, kineticjs

So I've made a multiplayer space shooter using node.js, socket.io and kineticJS. 
My Node.js server does not actually serve the client's page. My client-side files are currently hosted in a local Apache server on my computer.

The node server is up and running on Heroku right now and I can't seem to be able to get socket.io loaded on the client-side. I keep getting the "io is not defined" error.
This is how I import the script:

```
    <script src="http://xxx-xxx-xxxx.herokuapp.com:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I have followed the instructions shown here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs
And my package.json file looks like this:

```
    {
    "name": "Grid-Frontier",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
      "socket.io": "0.9.x"
    },
    "engines": {
       "node": "0.6.x"
    }
    }
```

On localhost everything is fine and I can just do the following:

```
    // Importing on client side
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    // Server-side
    server.listen(8080);
    socket = io.listen(server);
```

Comment: Not related but just a reminder: Heroku does not support websockets, you should set xhr-polling

Comment: Did you follow this also? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku

Comment: Does `socket.io.js` actually load? Try browsing manually to the file location or using the Network tab in your developer tools. It sounds like the browser is having trouble loading the client side library.

Comment: @Mustafa Yes I did change socket.io to use XHR-polling.

Comment: You might wanna try http://nodejitsu.com, it is a better platform for nodejs apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Heroku allows you only to communicate in port 80, you cannot use other ports therefore the address should be: `http://xxx-xxx-xxxx.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js` **not port 5000.** Actually there is nothing on port 5000, it is internal to machine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Removing the port number works perfectly!
It seems I also had to change my Apache to bind to port 80 so that it matches that of heroku.